# What does this notation mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm starting to learn OpenCV in C++. I have a decent working knowledge of the python version of OpenCV, and I was wondering what the following would translate to in python? I'm trying to understand the math of the cv2.warpPerspective() function. My tiny python brain can't wrap its head around it.

```
w = w != 0.0f ? 1.f / w : 0.0f
```

So far all I get from this is that if 'w' is not equal to '0' then it will equal '1/w' otherwise 'w' will equal '0'

Is that right?

Comment: `?:` is a ternary conditional operator meaning if cond (`w != 0`) then return 2nd. arg. (`1.f / w`) else 3rd. arg (`0.0f`). Please, google for C++ condition operator to find more. I believe in Python it would be `1.0 / w if w != 0.0 else 0.0`.

Comment: *if 'w' is not equal to '0' then it will equal '1/w' otherwise 'w' will equal '0'* — well, it seems you already have your answer. What is your actual question?

Comment: It's equivalent to `if (w != 0.0f) { w = 1.f / w; } else { w = 0.0f; }`

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I was checking out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/c---numbers-and-operators and other sources, but I wasn't sure how all of the pieces fit together for this one line.

Comment: Found [SO: Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/7478597). (Yepp, I remembered right.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the `else { w = 0.0f; }` part is redundant

Comment: @StackDanny Yes, but it's still part of the conditional expression and so need to be part of the equivalent statement. Otherwise the statement would not be matching the expression.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right. I assume this is one of the cases where the ternary operator is a bit overkill and a single `if` does just fine. But I suppose the compiler will optimize the ternary away anyway.

Comment: @StackDanny Not to mention that the `if` statement is much clearer than the expression. Clearer code means easier to understand it and what it does, and also easier to maintain. The conditional expression is too often misused as a premature optimization in the belief that the compiler won't otherwise generate optimal code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes that is correct. If they would just write

```
w = 1.0 / w;
```

division by zero might occur. So adding the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) here is an OK way to handle this. A more intuitive alternative would be:

```
if (w != 0.0f){
   w = 1.0f / w;
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this when the timer is up.

Comment: thank you. When asking a question like this next time please consider spending a few more minutes researching so that questions like this can be avoided. Afterall they do not add any value to this site.